# How to match and remove any line containing a specific string?

Tags: regex

I have a huge directory list of URLs from my Web site. Example:

```
/folder/folder2/folder3/page.htm
/folder/folder2/folder3/page2.htm
/folder/folder2/folder3/page3.htm
/folder/folder2/folder3/page4.htm
```

I want to clean this list of all items that have `/folder2` in the path. I need a regular expression to perform a find and replace for everything that uses `/folder2/` and delete those lines from my list. So find/replace it with blank.

Does anyone know what the proper regular expression for this would be? I should specify I am using Dreamweaver as my editor, which may use different regular expressions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This expression will match the entire line such that the string "/folder2" occurs in it:

```
^.+?\/folder2/.+$
```

HTH.

Comment: Hi - this didn't work in Dreamweaver. Sorry I should have specified that was the program I am using. Maybe the regular expressions are different in Dreamweaver?

Comment: Hmmm...shouldn't be. This is plain-vanilla regex. Maybe it doesn't like my second forward-slash, which is unescaped...try this: `^.+\/folder2\/.+$`.

Comment: Nothing with that either. I have the "Use regular expressions" box checked as well, so it's just not finding any matches.

Comment: Simplified even further: `.+/folder2/.+`

Answer (score 0):

In Python that would be:

```
import re
regex = re.compile('.*/folder2/.*')
f = open("filtered_file.txt", "w")
map(lambda x: f.write(x), filter(lambda x: not regex.match(x), open("input.txt")))
f.close()
```