# Removing lines containing specific words in javascript

Tags: javascript

This script is supposed to take a list of links, transform some by changing some words and eliminate others containing specific string of characters.

The first part is ok. I need help with the second. The line

```
    x = x.replace(/^.+/category/.+$/mg, "");
```

doesn't work even if we change the + with *. I used sources from here ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2930852/javascript-how-to-remove-line-that-contain-specific-string) & [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763839/how-to-match-and-remove-any-line-containing-a-specific-string) ). So, help the noob.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h3>Instert your links</h3>

input:<br>
<textarea id="myTextarea">
http://example.com/ad/123.html
http://example.com/ad/345.html
http://example.com/ad/3567.html
http://example.com/category/fashion.html
http://example.com/ad/8910.html
http://example.com/category/sports.html



</textarea>



<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Get clean links</button>

<p id="links"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
        x = document.getElementById("myTextarea").value;
        x = x.replace(/http:\/\/example.com\/ad\//g, "http://example./com/story/"); 
        x = x.replace(/\n/g,"</br>");
        x = x.replace(/^.+/category/.+$/mg, "");
    document.getElementById("links").innerHTML = x;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: so you want to remove lines which have `category` in it?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to escape your forward slashes as you are also using them as the regex delimiter.

```
x = x.replace(/^.+\/category\/.+$/mg, "");
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to copy those lines in `<p>` remove line containing category in it.

change your function to

```
function myFunction() {
  x = document.getElementById("myTextarea").value;
  var lines = x.split("\n").filter( function(val){ 
    return val.indexOf( "category" ) == -1;
  });
  document.getElementById("links").innerHTML = lines.join( "<br>" );
}
```

Comment: Works! But you forgot to change the variable in the end. It's "lines" we're sending to p not x. Thank you.

Comment: @NachtundNebel made the changes.